# Craft Commerce: Soft Delete on Payment Methods?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I was just playing around with my payment methods. I deleted them. Then I tried to re-add them with the same names and settings but I couldn't. "Name "Manual" has already been taken."

Apparently they have been soft deleted? How do you reinstate a soft delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commerce soft deletes payment methods instead of hard deletes them because even if a payment method is no longer in use, you still need to be able to have a reference to them for existing orders.

You can "un-delete" the payment method by going into the `craft_commerce_paymentmethods` table in the database and changing the `isArchived` column from `1` back to `0`.